# Django(Python) registration doesnt work correctly

Tags: python, django, django-registration

I am trying to write right registration for my online store with confirmation via mail. Registration passes once a time, but after I click on "Register", the same registration page is loaded, so activation process isn't starting. But a new user is wrote into the database with such data (and this does not work every time), but I cannot enter the site with same data. This is my first site with registration, so it’s hard to find whats wrong.

Thanks for help.

Attach the code:

models.py:

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.dispatch import Signal
from .utilities import send_activation_notification

class AdvUser(AbstractUser):
    is_activated = models.BooleanField(default=True, db_index=True,
                                       verbose_name='Activated?')
    send_messages = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name=
    'Agreement for promotion messages')

    class Meta(AbstractUser.Meta):
        pass

    user_registered = Signal(providing_args=['instance'])

    def user_registered_dispatcher(sender, **kwargs):
        send_activation_notification(kwargs['instance'])

    user_registered.connect(user_registered_dispatcher)
```

forms.py:

```py
from django.contrib.auth import password_validation
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django import forms
from .models import AdvUser
from .models import user_registrated

class RegisterUserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True, label='Email')
    password1 = forms.CharField(
        label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput,
        help_text=
        password_validation.password_validators_help_text_html()
    )

    password2 = forms.CharField(
        label='Reenter password', widget=forms.PasswordInput,
        help_text='Reenter your password'
    )

    def clean_password1(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data['password1']
        if password1:
            password_validation.validate_password(password1)
        return password1

    def clean(self):
        super().clean()
        password1 = self.cleaned_data['password1']
        password2 = self.cleaned_data['password2']
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            errors = {'password2': ValidationError(
                'Passwords don't match', code='password_mismatch')}
            raise ValidationError(errors)

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data['password1'])
        user.is_active = False
        user.is_activated = False
        if commit:
            user.save()
        user_registrated.send(RegisterUserForm, instance=user)
        return user

        class Meta:
            model = AdvUser
            fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2',
                      'first_name', 'last_name', 'send_messages')
```

views.py:

```py
from django.views.generic import CreateView
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .forms import RegisterUserForm
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
from .models import AdvUser
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.core.signing import BadSignature
from .utilities import signer

@login_required
def profile(request):
    return render(request, 'registration/profile.html')

class Login_signinLoginView(LoginView):
    template_name = 'registration/registration.html'

class Login_signinLogoutView(LoginRequiredMixin, LogoutView):
    template_name = 'registration/logout.html'

class RegisterUserView(CreateView):
    model = AdvUser
    template_name = 'registration/registration.html'
    success_url = '/accounts/register/done/'
    form_class = RegisterUserForm

class RegisterDoneView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'registration/register_done.html'

    def user_activate(request, sign):
        try:
            username = signer.unsign(sign)
        except BadSignature:
            return render(request, 'registration/bad_signature.html')
        user = get_object_or_404(AdvUser, username=username)
        if user.is_activated:
            template = 'registration/user_is_activated.html'
        else:
            template = 'registration/activation_done.html'
            user.is_active = True
            user.is_activated = True
            user.save()
        return render(request, template)
```

urls.py:

```py
from django.urls import path, re_path
from django.conf.urls import include
from .views import Login_signinLoginView, Login_signinLogoutView
from .views import profile
from .views import RegisterUserView, RegisterDoneView
from .views import user_activate

urlpatterns = [
    path('accounts/login/', Login_signinLoginView.as_view(),
         name='login'),
    path('accounts/logout/', Login_signinLogoutView.as_view(), name=
    'logout'),
    path('accounts/register/', RegisterUserView.as_view(), name=
    'register'),
    path('accounts/register/done/', RegisterDoneView.as_view(), name=
    'register_done'),
    path('account/register/activate/<str:sign>/', user_activate, name=
    'register_activate'),
    path('/mainpage/', include('mainpage.urls')),
    path('accounts/profile/', profile, name='profile')
```

utilities.py:

```py
from django.core.signing import Signer
from dnipromuch.settings import ALLOWED_HOSTS
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

signer = Signer()


def send_activation_notification(user):
    if ALLOWED_HOSTS:
        host = 'http://' + ALLOWED_HOSTS[0]
    else:
        host = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/'
    context = {'user': user, 'host': host, 'sign':
        signer.sign(user.username)}
    subject = render_to_string('email/activation_letter_subject.txt',
                               context)
    body_text = render_to_string('email/activation_letter_body.txt',
                                 context)
    user.email_user(subject, body_text)
```

Comment: Welome so SO - please review the question section in order to understan how tp formulate an effective question - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: In your views.py and in the RegisterUserView class, you are not passing the template to the render function and returning it. Also I guess somehow you have to handle GET and POST requests in your class in separate functions. If possible also show us your registration page html template. What is the Submit button doing over there?